# Define common properties without inheritance

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way of defining common properties without using inheritance in Kotlin?

For example

If I have two classes that both require an "id" property.

```
class Dog() {
  var id: UUID?
}

class Cat() {
  var id: UUID?
}
```

The general JAVA way to solve this is introduce a super class

```
class Animal() {
  var id: UUID?
}
class Dog: Animal()
class Cat: Animal()
```

But now "Dog" and "Cat" are of type "Animal".  What if I introduce a "Chair" class that also requires a unique identifier.

Essentially what I want to the ability to create a set of properties I can include in a number of different classes for programming convenience only.  I don't want all the problems associated with inheritance.

Comment: No, this is the point of inheritance in the first place. Use an interface called `Identifiable` or something like that, or use annotations and reflection to find the `id` property. I'm not sure what you mean by "problems associated with inheritance."

Comment: Effective java Item 16 : Favour composition over inheritance

Comment: I have read this book, but how else do you expect to be able to retrieve `id` regardless of the type? The point of item 16 IIRC was mainly to say _do not_ extend a type when it is possible to use a member instead, such as `Point` vs `ColoredPoint`. This is a different issue.

Comment: This use case definitely shouts interface, and in Kotlin, you can have properties in interfaces, so it works. If you don't put any implementation in this interface, you won't be facing any of the problems described in the Effective Java item either.

Comment: Modern languages love to say they aren't exactly using "implementation inheritance" when they introduce things like traits, protocols, and interfaces. Kotlin's interfaces can have properties and default methods and should be perfect for what you want. All without "the problems associated with inheritance."

Comment: I was initially thinking composable objects in kotlin might be the solution here but from my research it will not. Being new to Kotlin I was thinking that the language might have a nice way of doing this.

Comment: @RayToal so it looks like an interface is the way to go.  Annotations on the interface properties will be respected I assume.

Comment: any conclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments:

```
interface Animal {
    var id: UUID?
}
class Dog: Animal
class Cat: Animal
```

Answer (score 5):

You can, of course, use an `interface` instead of a base class:

```
interface HasId {
    val id: UUID
}

data class Dog(override val id: UUID) : HasId
data class Cat(override val id: UUID) : HasId
```

However, the above is still using inheritance. If you have more common properties that would be used in multiple classes it may be a sign that they should be grouped together to form a separate value object e.g.

```
data class Address(val city: String, val street: String, val country: String)

class Person(val name: String, val address: Address)
class School(val name: String, val address: Address, val studentsCount: Int)
```

And if you want to treat `Person` and `School` uniformly with regards to `address` property you can still use the interface to denote the common attribute:

```
interface HasAddress {
    val address: Address
}

class Person(val name: String,
             override val address: Address) : HasAddress

class School(val name: String,
             override val address: Address,
             val studentsCount: Int) : HasAddress
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible that delegation will suit your needs:

```
interface WithId {
    var id: Int
}

class IdStorage : WithId {
    override var id: Int = 0
}

class Dog(withId: WithId) : WithId by withId {
    constructor() : this(IdStorage()) {}
}

class Cat(withId: WithId) : WithId by withId {
    constructor() : this(IdStorage()) {}
}
```

This code is rather verbose, but what it allows you to do is:

- Avoid using superclass just for the sake of having `id` property, which allows you to extend other classes if you need
- Usage of interface, which guarantees other pieces of code that your class has `id`
- Allows to move implementation of your properties (or functions) to separate class, hence no need for duplicate code in case of complex property/function implementation
- Allows implementing *multiple* properties/functions in a separate class